# How to know the direction in which recyclerview cell is being swiped?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, itemtouchhelper

To my recyclerview I have attached ItemTouchHelper. User can swipe in both direction i.e. left and right.

I would like to know is it possible to know as soon as user starts to drag a cell towards left or right and not after user have swiped the cell of recyclerview. Based on that I need to take some action on the cell.

I was going through the following method of ItemTouchHelper

```
@Override
    public int getDragDirs(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {

        return super.getDragDirs(recyclerView, viewHolder);
    }
```

but I don't know how to use it as the documentation is not proper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the direction of the swipe in `onChildDraw()` of `ItemTouchHelper.Callback` as soon as the view being swiped is selected and starts to move right or left:

```
@Override
public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
    if (actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_SWIPE) {
        // Here, if dX > 0 then swiping right. 
        // If dX < 0 then swiping left. 
        // If dX == 0 then at at start position.
    } else {
        super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
new ItemTouchHelper( new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback( 0,
        ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT ) {
    @Override
    public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView,
                          RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
        int adapterPosition = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
        if (direction == ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
            Toast.makeText( getContext(), "Right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        } else if (direction == ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {
            Toast.makeText( getContext(), "Left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        }

    }
} ).attachToRecyclerView( myProductFgRecyclerV );
```